# Clear Folder before write Sink Azure Data Factory "The specified path does not exist"

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have the a Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 that has been aggregated to parquets:

Dataset source2 that reads from the output path /output/partitions
Dataset sink that writes to the same path as source 2 /output/partitions

When I select the clear folder in sink I get the

> "Job failed due to reason: at Sink 'sink1': Operation failed:
> \"The specified path does not exist.\", 404, HEAD,

It also says to run below to clear the cache:

> 'REFRESH TABLE tableName'

It writes all the other partitions but is there a way to read the same ADLS Gen2 folder and overwrite it

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced this and got same error when I check the clear the folder option.

[image]

I have tried with other options and observed that the new parquets are created. So, to delete the existing parquets you can use the below approach.

The Idea is after the dataflow, delete the old files by their last modified date using delete activity.

To filter out the old files use utcNow() function. The last modified date of old files is less than utcNow().

First store the `@utcNow()` value in a variable before the dataflow.

This is my pipeline picture:

[image]

After the dataflow, use the Get Meta data activity to get all **parquet(old+new)** files list.

[image]

Give this list to ForEach and inside ForEach use another GetMeta data for `lastModifieddate`. For this Use another parquet dataset with parameter.

[image]

Now compare this Last modified date to our variable in if condition. If this results true use delete activity inside True activities of if.

If condition:

```
@greater(variables('timebeforedf'),activity('Get Metadata2').output.lastModified)
```

[image]

In Delete activity give the `@item().name` inside True activities.

[image]

My Result parquet files after Execution:

[image]

Comment: This is a thoughtful process - any thoughts on performance?  It will take me a little bit to implement. so hope to update you soon.

Comment: I think for large number of files you can try `rm /folder1/*` in the Data flow sink settings File pre command which will delete old files before transforming and creates new files. Refer this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-data-lake-storage?tabs=data-factory#sink-properties) to learn more about it.